# How to find key with type objectId , ref to <some model>

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have created a Notes model having schema as shown below

```
const notesschema = new Schema({
user :{
    type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref : 'User',
    required : true
},
problem : {
    type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref : 'Problems',
    required : true
},
content : {
    type : 'string'
}
 },{
timestamps : true
})
```

To show the User his notes for a particular task/problem I am trying to fetch notes and show to him and possibly update if he do some changes and save, The problem is with this schema I dont know how to write <model.findById >API to find notes from my notes model having particular user and specific task/problem.Which I would know the Id of.

With this particular schema , and my current knowledge i would have to write So much code. So if there is any easier way to do this task is welcomed, 
 I was also thinking to change my schema and just placing my user id in my schema instead of whole user and finding notes from my database

edit : as suggested by all the answers we can simply find using user.id which I thought initially would not word as that was just the path, but which stores actually user.id

Comment: sorry but I couldn't understand your question

Comment: Sorry for that, I tried to edit my question a bit, If there is any specific thing, you want me to edit, I will try to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create the notes' collection the same way you're doing it,

```js
const notesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User', // # the name of the user model
    required: true
  },
  problem: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Problem', // # the name of the user model
    required: true
  },
  content: String
})
```

Then you'll create the model of the notesSchema as follows:

```
const NoteModel = mongoose.model('Note', notesSchema, 'notes')
```

export them so you can use them in your controllers:

```js
module.exports = {
  NoteModel,
  notesSchema
}
```

**or** if you're using +es6 modules (think of, if you're using TypeScript):

```js
export default {
  NoteModel,
  notesSchema
}
```

This will result in creating the following table (*collection*) in the database:

[image]

Let's think of the following challenges:

**To get all the notes:**

```
NoteModel.find({})
```

**To get all the users:**

```js
UserModel.find({}) // you should have something like this in your code of course
```

**To get all the problems:**

```js
ProblemModel.find({}) // you should have something like this in your code of course
```

---

**To get all the notes of a user:**

```js
NotesModel.find({ user: USER_ID })
```

**To search for notes by problem*s*:**

```js
NotesModel.find({ problem: PROBLEM_ID })
```

---

Now, the above is how you do it in mongoose, now let's create a RESTFUL controller for all of that: (assuming you're using express)

```js
const expressAsyncHandler = require('express-async-handler') // download this from npm if you want
app.route('/notes').get(expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const data = await NotesModel.find(req.query)
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    data,
  })
}))
```

The `req.query` is what's going to include the search filters, the search filters will be sent by the client (the front-end) as follows:

```
http://YOUR_HOST:YOUR_PORT/notes?user=TheUserId
http://YOUR_HOST:YOUR_PORT/notes?problem=TheProblemId
http://YOUR_HOST:YOUR_PORT/notes?content=SomeNotes
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const notesschemaOfUser = await notesschema.findOne({user: user_id});
```